# how to change a value of drop down and to trigger a onchange functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if it is possible to change a value of a dropdown box dynamically and to trigger an ajax onchange function assigned to this dropdown at the same time.

so far I can only change the value of a dropdown box but the onchange function is not being called.

here is the dropdown:

```
<select name="ProductSelector" id="ProductSelector" onchange="getItems(this.value)">
  <option value="">--Select Item--</option>
  <option value="one"> Option one</option>
  <option value="two"> Option Two</option>
  <option value="three"> Option Three</option>
</select>
```

when I do this operation:

```
document.getElementById("ProductSelector").value = "one";
```

the value of the dropdown is changing, but the `getItems` function is not being triggered.

What am I doing wrong or may be there is another way to change a value of the doropdown which will allow me to trigger my ajax function as well?

I don't want to use JQuery. I just wandering why the function is not working if I use dinamic change and on manual change it works fine?

Comment: Whats your actual problem the code is working fine [Check Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nsisodia91/4fvwn2Lx/)

Comment: the problem is that the `getItems` function is not being triggered when I change value dinamically

Comment: if I manually select something there it work perfectly. But if the chagne comes from code the function is not called

Comment: So post some relevant code too then'

Comment: @mistersweet Which browser you are using?

Comment: but in the getItems I include options for all borwsers: `if(window.XMLHttpRequest){//safari, chrome, opera, ffox
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else{//IE
      ActiveXObject("Microft.XMLHTTP");
   }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you are changing the value with JavaScript and the `change` event isn't triggering. So, lets trigger it then.

Trigger the event `change` every time you change the value via JavaScript.

**No jQuery used.**

Try this:

```js
function changeVal() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("ProductSelector"),
    event = new Event('change');

  elem.value = "one";
  elem.dispatchEvent(event);
}


function getItems(val) {
  alert(val);
}

changeVal();
```

```html
<select name="ProductSelector" id="ProductSelector" onchange="getItems(this.value)">
  <option value="">--Select Item--</option>
  <option value="one">Option one</option>
  <option value="two">Option Two</option>
  <option value="three">Option Three</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I mostly do it this way:

HTML:

```
<select class="class-name">

    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>

</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$(".class-name").on("change", function() {

    var value = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url: "your-php-script.php",
        data: { 'value' : value },
        success: function (data) {

             alert('This has changed');

        }

    );    

});
```

Comment: is there any way in javasript? most of my functions are written in jacascript and if I add jquery it will mess the staff up

Answer (score 0):

Problem is changing the value with JS will not trigger the change event. Best solution would be to write a function which changes the value and triggers the change event manually.

**HTML**

```
<select name="ProductSelector" id="ProductSelector">
    <option value="">--Select Item--</option>
    <option value="one"> Option one</option>
    <option value="two"> Option Two</option>
    <option value="three"> Option Three</option>
</select>
```

**JS** (no jQuery)

```
//define the element so we can access it more easily
var element = document.getElementById('ProductSelector');
//define the event we want to trigger manually later
var event = new Event('change');

//add eventlistener which is triggered by selecItem()
element.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
    getItems(event.target.value);
});

function getItems(val) {
    alert(val);
}

//set the value and trigger the event manually
function selectItem(value){
    //select the item without using the dropdown
    element.value = value;
    //trigger the event manually
    element.dispatchEvent(event);
}

//using a function with the option you want to choose
selectItem("three");
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dytd96cb/4/)**

Use the working JSFiddle: Note that you have to uncomment the last line of code.

Comment: so `.valie =` option is not actually considered as a change in a value of drop box?

Comment: at least it will not trigger the change event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<body>


Select your favorite value:
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
  <option value="value3">value3</option>
  <option value="value4">value4</option>
</select>


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $( "#mySelect" ).change(function() {



    var value = $(this).val();      

    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url: "request-url.php",
        data: { 'value' : value },
        success: function (data) {

             alert('the ajax request has been send');

        }

    );    


}); 


});


</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try removing the `onchange=""` attribute from the select input and just use the jQuery to check for changes:

```
$('body').on('change', "#ProductSelector", function(){
  var id = $(this).val();
   //now do your ajax call with the value selected
});
```

Comment: is there anything in without jquery?

Comment: jquery was not an option and it still does not solve the problem at all.

Answer (score -1):

> "What am I doing wrong or may be there is another way to change a value of the doropdown which will allow me to trigger my ajax function as well?"

Another way of adding the event listener is by doing it "[unobtrusive style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)".

```js
document.getElementById('ProductSelector').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  getItems(event.target.value);
});

function getItems(val) {
  // Todo: whatever needs to be done :-)
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<select name="ProductSelector" id="ProductSelector">
  <option value="">--Select Item--</option>
  <option value="one">Option one</option>
  <option value="two">Option Two</option>
  <option value="three">Option Three</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dytd96cb/

Comment: how about without JQuery. I don't like it particularly.

Comment: The above example is without jQuery. @mistersweet

Comment: your example still does not trigger the alert, if the value is changed using js.

Comment: where do I pass the desired parameter in your example?

Comment: In the code you posted, you want to pass the <select>'s value. This is passed via event.target.value in my example.